# Extracting AC-3 from MPEG Transport Stream

Tags: mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

I am writing a demultiplexer for MPEG Transport Stream which should extract Audio and Video 
access points.
Assume i have an Audio PID and that i know it is AC-3 audio.
Also assume that i collected all the PID's TS packets and assembles their PESes.

1.How can i extract the AC-3 access points? 
  by what i read so far the AC-3 header should start with 0x0B 0xFF, however by looking at 
  the PES's  payload it is not there...
2.The AC-3's PES streamID is PRIVATE_STREAM_1. does it has the "Optional PES header"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PES header is defined under MPEG2 systems - which was created before AAC.

PES packetization is general purpose and hence there is no notion of private/special headers depending on any codec.

All payload of PES (i.e. data other than PES header) -concatenated forms the ES stream for any codec.